# Eclipse bug on Windows 8.1

Tags: eclipse

When I enter Eclipse, this error message pops up - "Could not find msmtch.dll" . I can't find any information on that and I don't understand what it means or what to do. I have already tried reinstalling but it keeps happening

Comment: Are you sure there's not a typo in there? Which version of Eclipse, installed how, with which version of Java?